# DatabaseError at /accounts/register/

Tags: python, django

День добрый, пытаюсь прикрутить регистрацию на сайте, руководствуясь [статьёй](http://habrahabr.ru/post/74165/), и натыкаюсь на ошибку

> `DatabaseError at /accounts/register/
> relation "phone_book_userprofile" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...d_at", "phone_book_userprofile"."updated_at" FROM "phone_boo...`
>                                                              ^
> `Request Method:   POST
> Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/
> Django Version: 1.4
> Exception Type: DatabaseError
> Exception Value:    
> relation "phone_book_userprofile" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...d_at", "phone_book_userprofile"."updated_at" FROM "phone_boo...`
>                                                              ^
> `Exception Location:   /home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in execute, line 52
> Python Executable:  /home/makc/djcode/Blog/bin/python
> Python Version: 2.7.3
> Python Path:    
> ['/home/makc/djcode/phone_book',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.4.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2012d-py2.7.egg',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/lib/python2.7',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
>  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
>  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>  '/home/makc/djcode/Blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`

Подскажите, в каком направлении копать.

Comment: `syncdb` и/или `migrate` выполнили?

Comment: syncdb выполнил

Comment: `migrate`?

Comment: syncdb --migrate

Answer (score 2):

```
DatabaseError at /accounts/register/ relation "phone_book_userprofile" does not exist LINE 1: ...d_at", "phone_book_userprofile"."updated_at" FROM "phone_boo... ^
```

отношение(связь) "phone_book_userprofile" не существует.
Проверяйте Ваши модели book, userprofile